# How to save enum field in the database room?

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-room, converters

I must write the value from the `enum` enumeration to the database. An error occurs during compilation. What am I doing wrong?

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "state_of_health")
@TypeConverters(HealthConverter::class)
var health: Health

enum class Health(val value: Int){
    NONE(-1),
    VERY_BAD(0),
    ...
}

class HealthConverter{

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromHealth(value: Health): Int{
        return value.ordinal
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toHealth(value: Int): Health{
        return when(value){
            -1 -> Health.NONE
            0 -> Health.VERY_BAD
            ...
            else -> Health.EXCELLENT
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you should annotate your `Database` class with `@TypeConverters` annotation (and not your `enum class`). Check https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can make a convert to each enum, like this:

```
class Converters {

     @TypeConverter
     fun toHealth(value: String) = enumValueOf<Health>(value)

     @TypeConverter
     fun fromHealth(value: Health) = value.name
}
```

Or if you prefer store it as SQL `integer`, you can use ordinal too:

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toHealth(value: Int) = enumValues<Health>()[value]

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromHealth(value: Health) = value.ordinal
}
```

Unfortunatally, there is no way to use generics `Enum<T>` to accomplish this since unbound generics will raise an error `Cannot use unbound generics in Type Converters`.

Android Room team could seriously add an annotation and a generator for Enums to their kapt compiler.

Finally, annotate a database class, entity class, dao class, dao method, dao method parameter or entity field class with this:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
```

Comment: How to use the enum in the dataclass? With the value or enum?

Comment: @Rafael After using the type converter, you can directly use enum in your entity class.

Answer (score 34):

This is no longer an issue in [version 2.3.0-alpha4](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0-alpha04): "Room will now default to using an Enum to String and vice versa type converter if none is provided. If a type converter for an enum already exists, Room will prioritize using it over the default one."

"If a one-way type converter for reading already exists for the Enum, Room might accidentally use the built-in String to Enum converter which might not be desired. This is a known issue and can be fixed by making it a two-way converter."

Answer (score 15):

To fix this annotate your `Database` class with `@TypeConverters` annotation (and not your `enum class`).

Example:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Check https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

Comment: Is there any oher way? In JPA is so much easier.

Comment: @AllanVeloso, what do you want to have as the "other way"? Alternatively, you can hold a basic type data in your models (like enum ordinal as `Int`, or enum name as `String`, etc.), but will it be better? Also, don't know what the JPA is...

Comment: JPA = Java Persistence API. It handles persistence of Enum classes with a simple annotation @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) or @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) on the field. In this way you don't need to create a converter to each enum.

Comment: @AllanVeloso, maybe following a single interface by all enums is what might help. I've added to my answer.

Comment: Not good either, everytime that you define a enum option you will have to override the getId() method. I tried to use generics, inline retified, and generics. but room does not support it either, error `Cannot use unbound generics in Type Converters`. Better convert it manually.

Comment: @AllanVeloso, why do you need generics here? Can you please share what you have tried?

Comment: ``` @TypeConverter
        inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> toEnum(value: String?): Enum<T>? {
            return if (value != null) enumValueOf<T>(value)
            else null
        }

        @TypeConverter
        inline fun <reified T: Enum<*>> fromEnum(value: Enum<*>?): String? {
            return value?.name
        }
```

Comment: @AllanVeloso, you're right. It cannot be 100% generalized in an easy way.

Answer (score 11):

Enum class;

```
enum class Priority {
HIGH,
MEDIUM,
LOW
}
```

Converter class;

```
class Converter {

@TypeConverter
fun fromPriority(priority: Priority): String {
    return priority.name
}

@TypeConverter
fun toPriority(priority: String): Priority {
    return Priority.valueOf(priority)
}

}
```

usage;

```
@Database(entities = [MyData::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converter::class)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

  // todo

}
```

Comment: Could the class "Converter " include all of the converters you want?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes

Comment: @Milan Nice. Thanks you.

Answer (score 5):

For java developers

The Enum

```
public enum Health {
    NONE(-1),
    VERY_BAD(0);

    public final int value;

    Health(int newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The type converter

```
public class HealthConverter {

    /**
     * Convert Health to an integer
     */
    @TypeConverter
    public static int fromHealthToInt(Health value) {
        return value.ordinal();
    }

    /**
     * Convert an integer to Health
     */
    @TypeConverter
    public static Health fromIntToHealth(int value) {
        return (Health.values()[value]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Room version 2.3.0 you can save Enum Look here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?hl=ru#version_230_3