# How to store Kotlin Enum with Room using Gson in TypeConverter?

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, gson, typeconverter

I faced problems trying to save **Kotlin Enum with Room as JSON (using Gson)**. I've completely followed [official Google instruction](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) and add TypeConverter, but it keeps giving an error: *Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.*

My **entity** class:

```
@Entity(tableName = TextHighlight.TABLE_NAME)
data class TextHighlight.TABLE_NAME(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    var id: Long = 0,

    @TypeConverters(HighlightingColorConverter::class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_HIGHLIGHT)
    var color: HighlightingColor

) {
```

My **Kotlin Enum** class:

```
enum class HighlightingColor(

    @SerializedName("rgb")
    var rgb: String,

    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String

)
```

My **TypeConverter**:

```
class HighlightingColorConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromHighlightingColor(highlight: HighlightingColor) = Gson().toJson(highlight)

    @TypeConverter
    fun toHighlightingColor(s: String): HighlightingColor =
        Gson().fromJson(s, HighlightingColor::class.java)

}
```

Can't understand what's wrong. Please, help to figure it out!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60079133/1029110 Gson is not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sometime I've figured how to fix it.

1. TypeConverter functions should be placed in `companion object` and has `@JvmStatic` annotation. It sound logical because these functions should be static in java.
2. `@TypeConverters` annotation should be placed not above entity filed, but above hole entity data class.

Final code is:

```
@TypeConverters(TextHighlight.HighlightingColorConverter::class)
@Entity(tableName = TextHighlight.TABLE_NAME)
data class TextHighlight(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID)
    var id: Long = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_HIGHLIGHT)
    var color: HighlightingColor

) {

    class HighlightingColorConverter {

        companion object {

            @JvmStatic
            @TypeConverter
            fun fromHighlightingColor(highlight: HighlightingColor) = Gson().toJson(highlight)

            @JvmStatic
            @TypeConverter
            fun toHighlightingColor(s: String): HighlightingColor =
                Gson().fromJson(s, HighlightingColor::class.java)

        }

    }

}
```