# Android Room: Save Enum in Entity

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-room

I'm trying to store an enum value in a Room database on Android. However, I'm getting a null pointer exception when the entity is fetched from our API and attempted to be saved to the DB. I've tried annotating both the Database class and my Entity class with the `@Typeconverters` annotation.

My Entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@TypeConverters(SalesOrderStatusConverter::class)
data class SalesOrder(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    ...
    var salesOrderStatus: SalesOrderStatus,
    ...
)
```

With an enum class and converter in the same file:

```
enum class SalesOrderStatus(value: Int) {
    UNPACKED(0),
    PACKED(1),
    SHIPPED(2),
    EXPORT(3)
}

class SalesOrderStatusConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toSalesOrderStatus(value: Int): SalesOrderStatus = enumValues<SalesOrderStatus>()[value]

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromSalesOrderStatus(value: SalesOrderStatus): Int = value.ordinal
}
```

When I navigate to the appropriate fragment in the app, I get the following error message and the app crashes after data is fetched from the API and attempted to be saved:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is
> null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter,
> parameter value
> at com.android.sampleappname.data.model.SalesOrderStatusConverter.fromSalesOrderStatus(Unknown
> Source:2)

Things work as expected when I change `var salesOrderStatus: SalesOrderStatus` to `var salesOrderStatus: Int`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `@TypeConverters` used with `RoomDatabase` class

Comment: @StanislavBondar I've tried that as well, same issue unfortunately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save enum field in the database room?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326789/how-to-save-enum-field-in-the-database-room)

Comment: @AlirezaTizfahmFard no, I've tried annotating my database class with the TypeConverters annotation as well

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation @ProvideTypeConverter on your converter class, like this:

```
   @ProvidedTypeConverter
class SalesOrderStatusConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toSalesOrderStatus(value: Int): SalesOrderStatus = enumValues<SalesOrderStatus>()[value]
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromSalesOrderStatus(value: SalesOrderStatus): Int = value.ordinal
}
```

And remove from your data class, SalesOrder