# How to restrict Int values bound to database column?

Tags: kotlin

data class:

```
// Entity of query
@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
data class HistoryItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = SEARCHED_DOMAIN)
    val searchedDomain: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = STATUS)
    val status: Int,
)
```

And object of statuses:

```
object Statuses { 
    const val FAILURE = 0
    const val NOT_FOUND = 1
    const val FOUND = 2
}
```

How to make val status: Int to always be FAILURE or NOT_FOUND or FOUND? I think it should looks like this:

```
@Status
@ColumnInfo(name = STATUS)
val status: Int
```

But how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using an [enum class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html) for this:

```kotlin
enum class Status { 
    FAILURE, NOT_FOUND, FOUND;
}

@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
data class HistoryItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = SEARCHED_DOMAIN)
    val searchedDomain: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = STATUS)
    val status: Status
)
```

However, older versions of Android Room (prior to 2.3.0) do not automatically convert enum classes, so if you're using these you will need to use a type convertor:

```kotlin
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toStatus(value: Int) = enumValues<Status>()[value]

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromStatus(value: Status) = value.ordinal
}
```

Which requires you to add the following to your database definition:

```kotlin
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60079133/8819761).

Comment: There is Built-in Enum convertor since Room 2.3.0 https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0

Comment: Great, I'll mention this in the answer