# Why is the result of this room query not showing anything

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-viewmodel

So the DAO in my room database contains this query

```
@Dao
interface RecordsDAO {
    //Other queries

    @Query("SELECT * FROM BloodPressureRecords WHERE recordStatus IN (:list) ORDER BY createdAt DESC")
    fun getSelectedRecords(list: List<RecordStatus>): Flow<List<Record>>
}
```

Looks like this and should return records if thery are in a list that I provide,

I have created a data class to create a record and looks like this

```
@Entity(tableName = "BloodPressureRecords")
data class Record(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val systolicPressure: String,
    val diastolicPressure: String,
    val pulse: String,
    val createdAt: Long = Clock.System.now().toEpochMilliseconds(),
    val recordStatus: RecordStatus = RecordStatus.NEW
)
```

Record status is a simple enum class structured like this,
I don't believe I need a type converter in order to use this in room

```
enum class RecordStatus {
    NEW,
    EXPORTED,
    ARCHIVED,
    ERROR
}
```

However when I call the getRequiredRecords it does not seem to provide any records
I call it in the view model when creating state in my ViewModel

This is done here

```
//Other view model stuff
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(BloodPressureState())
    private val _selectedState = MutableStateFlow(SelectedState())

    val state = combine(
        _state,
        _selectedState,
        repository.getRequiredRecords(_selectedState.value.selectedRecords)
    ){state, selectedState, requiredRecords ->
        state.copy(
            records = requiredRecords,
            isNewSelected = selectedState.isNewSelected,
            isExportedSelected = selectedState.isExportedSelected,
            isArchivedSelected = selectedState.isArchivedSelected
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), BloodPressureState())
//Other view model stuff
```

I created the BloodPressureState like this

```
data class BloodPressureState(
    //Other states
    val records: List<Record> = emptyList(),
    val isNewSelected: Boolean = true,
    val isExportedSelected: Boolean = false,
    val isArchivedSelected: Boolean = false,
    //Other states
)
```

And the SelectedState like this

```
data class SelectedState (
    val isNewSelected: Boolean = true,
    val isExportedSelected: Boolean = false,
    val isArchivedSelected: Boolean = false,
    val selectedRecords: List<RecordStatus> = emptyList<RecordStatus>()
)
```

I add and remove selected RecordStatus' from the list with the use of the check box, however when I try to display on my screen nothing appears, I believe the error to be in the business logic but please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I just had to lift the getRequiredRecords out of the combine function, so that that part of the code looks like this:

```
val state = combine(
        _state,
        _selectedState,
    ){state, selectedState ->
        state.copy(
            records = repository.getRequiredRecords(selectedState.selectedRecords),
            isNewSelected = selectedState.isNewSelected,
            isExportedSelected = selectedState.isExportedSelected,
            isArchivedSelected = selectedState.isArchivedSelected
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), BloodPressureState())
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your `recordStatus` field since you're trying to store an enum class. You can use just the name of the enum item or something similar.

If you really need to store the enum class itself, you will need to create a custom [@TypeConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326789/how-to-save-enum-field-in-the-database-room). Refer to this link for more information on how to do that.

Comment: Room automatically generates type converters for an enum class but cheers anyway. I believe I found the problem in my answer.